# Onclick Method is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have this simple html:

```
<head>
  <script src="~/js/Order.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button-1" onclick="ButtonClick(this.id);">This is a button</button>
  ...
</body>
```

And this is my Order.js file:

```
function ButtonClick(buttonID)
{
    alert("Button " + buttonID + " pressed!");
}
```

But when I click on the button, the console outputs, that `ButtonClick is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`.

But this is not true, it definitely is defined in my Order.js file

Comment: working fine :- https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/9vmhjb0z/

Comment: Please make sure your Order.js is successfully imported.

Comment: It might be the fault of Visual Studio, but I can't see what would be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was an error in another function of the script, and so Visual Studio did not distribute my js file. When I commented the faulty method it worked again